# How to convert an address to bytes in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses, bytes

What is the recommended way to convert an `address` to `bytes` in Solidity?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To be even more efficient:

```
function toBytes(address a) public pure returns (bytes memory b){
    assembly {
        let m := mload(0x40)
        a := and(a, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
        mstore(add(m, 20), xor(0x140000000000000000000000000000000000000000, a))
        mstore(0x40, add(m, 52))
        b := m
   }
}
```

Takes just 695 gas vs 2500 for Gokulnath's answer and 5000 for Eth's

Edit for solidity ^0.5.0:

This is almost as efficient and much more readable:

```
function toBytes(address a) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
    return abi.encodePacked(a);
}
```

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: Does this still work in solidity ^0.5.0?

Comment: With some minor syntax tweaks, yes

Answer (score 17):

Here is my tiny one-liner for `address` to `bytes32` conversion:

```
bytes32(uint256(uint160(addr)) << 96);
```

If you need `bytes` instead of `bytes32`:

```
abi.encodePacked(addr)
```

Comment: This answers a different question because `bytes` is different from `bytes32`.

Comment: Also, note that this will pad the bytes32 to the **right**. Normally, in Ethereum, we pad to the **left**. Just omit the `<< 96` to do that.

Comment: This answer does not work today. It says cannot convert address type to uint.

Comment: @YulePale, fixed!

Answer (score 6):

There are no current shortcuts and you need to write your own function.

Here's the function suggested by Solidity's author,
[chriseth:](https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity?at=56b085b5eaf741c118d65198)

```
function toBytes(address x) returns (bytes b) {
    b = new bytes(20);
    for (uint i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        b[i] = byte(uint8(uint(x) / (2**(8*(19 - i)))));
}
```

Comment: If you want to convert an address to a string, you can then convert the bytes to a string just using explicit conversion, as `string(b)`

Comment: Getting this error in browser solidity:

`Error: Type string memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage pointer.`

Comment: @koampapapa I looked into it and answered your question http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8346/convert-address-to-string-msg-sender  If really needed, consider doing conversions in the UI/frontend/Javascript instead of Solidity to save gas.

Comment: Later can we convert `bytes`(b) to `bytes32` to store it in `bytes32` format? @eth

Comment: @alper It would be better to directly cast the address to a `bytes20`, which will work wherever you wanted to use `bytes32`.

Comment: In order to user it as `bytes32`, could I do something like: `bytes memory b = toBytes(a);
 assembly {
           result := mload(add(b, 32))
  }
` @eth

Answer (score 4):

Here is an one-line solution.

```
abi.encodePacked(addr)
```

It's simple and costs little

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  It is tempting to write a short answer, but too short is not helpful.  For example, what does "costs little" mean?  Is there a comparison of gas compared to the accepted answer?  Which versions of Solidity can this be used for?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to convert address to raw bytes, it is often easier to use ABI encoding. ABI encoding is not raw byte-to-byte translation, but it adds its own marker bytes to separate fields. However you can perform this with one built-in function.

In Solidity

```
 /**
   * A test method exposed to be called from clients to compare that ABI packing and hashing
   * is same across different programming languages.
   *
   * Does ABI encoding for an address and then calculates KECCAK-256 hash over the bytes.
   *
   * https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3
   *
   */
  function calculateAddressHash(address a) public pure returns (bytes32 hash, bytes memory data) {

    // First we ABI encode the address to bytes.
    // This is so called "tight packing"
    // https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3
    bytes memory packed = abi.encodePacked(a);

    // Then we calculate keccak256 over the resulting bytes
    bytes32 hashResult = keccak256(packed);

    return(hashResult, packed);
  }
```

In JavaScript/TypeScript

```
  import { soliditySha3 } from 'web3-utils';

  // Sign address
  const { signature, v, r, s } = signAddress(user2);

  // This is an address is a hexadecimal format
  const ourData = user2.toLowerCase();

  // https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#id23
  // Convert address to bytes using "tight packing"
  // and them calculates keccak-256 over the resulting bytes
  const ourHash = soliditySha3({t: 'address', v: user2 });

  // We hash data in similar in TypeScript and Solidity
  const { hash, data } = await tokenSwap.calculateAddressHash(user2);
  assert(ourData.toLowerCase() == data.toLowerCase());
  assert(ourHash.toLowerCase() == hash.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: This may be clear to those who already know what you're doing, but adding some examples would help make this clearer to those who don't.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the answer given above but is more gas efficient as it is in assembly.

```
  function addressToBytes(address i)  returns (bytes by) { 
    by = new bytes(20); 
    assembly { 
      let count := 0 
      let byptr := add(by, 32) 
      loop: 
          jumpi(end, eq(count, 20)) 
          mstore8(byptr, byte(add(count,12), i)) 
          byptr := add(byptr, 1) 
          count := add(count, 1) 
          jump(loop) 
      end: 
    } 
    return by; 
  }
```

Comment: There's really no need for a loop at all, since we're dealing with < 32 bytes

Comment: Yes, there is no need of loop. Good one.