# Convert address to string

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, addresses, string

In Solidity, how can I convert the sender address to a string?

The comments in 
[How to convert an address to bytes in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/884/how-to-convert-an-address-to-bytes-in-solidity) did not provide a working solution

Comment: function toString(address x) internal pure returns (string) { bytes memory b = new bytes(20); for (uint i = 0; i < 20; i++) b[i] = byte(uint8(uint(x) / (2**(8*(19 - i))))); return string(b); } Use `internal pure` keyword, otherwise you will get a warning. For more information about [pure function](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#pure-functions).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Use `abi.encodePacked(x)`

where `x` is the address. (Thanks [@k06a](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/3032/k06a))

Comment: It works, but the result is not a human-readable string. For a human-readable string, see `toAsciiString` example in the other answer.

Comment: can not be used together with string.concat (0.8.x) ( error message: `Invalid type for argument in the string.concat function call. string type is required, but t_bytes_memory_ptr provided` ) , the `toAsciiString` works for me.

Comment: @Siwei Thanks, I upvoted that answer. This type of question puzzles me because it may be an anti-pattern: generally should try to avoid such conversions in a contract and do them elsewhere like the frontend...

Answer (score 28):

I was not able to read the ABI-encoded string with web3.js. Therefore, I added some conversion to the ASCII characters:

```
function toAsciiString(address x) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    bytes memory s = new bytes(40);
    for (uint i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        bytes1 b = bytes1(uint8(uint(uint160(x)) / (2**(8*(19 - i)))));
        bytes1 hi = bytes1(uint8(b) / 16);
        bytes1 lo = bytes1(uint8(b) - 16 * uint8(hi));
        s[2*i] = char(hi);
        s[2*i+1] = char(lo);            
    }
    return string(s);
}

function char(bytes1 b) internal pure returns (bytes1 c) {
    if (uint8(b) < 10) return bytes1(uint8(b) + 0x30);
    else return bytes1(uint8(b) + 0x57);
}
```

Comment: There was a problem with the function char(byte b). "TypeError:  Operator < not compatible with types bytes1 and int_const 10" I suppose this comparison does work anyway since you probably meant if b is a number then add 0x30 to it. But how do you know if a byte is less than 10 or not anyways?

Comment: `if (b < 10)` has to be changed to `if (uint8(b) < 10)`, then the `Operator < not compatible with types bytes1 ...` error is fixed. I made an edit to the answer. Hope it gets approved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - so far this works in v0.5.10

Comment: This conversion looses the address checksum, which is case sensitive. The checksum can be restored using `Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress()`.

Comment: The address  is formated to lowercase without initial 0x

Answer (score 18):

This is method to convert `address` to hex `string`:

```
function toString(address account) public pure returns(string memory) {
    return toString(abi.encodePacked(account));
}

function toString(uint256 value) public pure returns(string memory) {
    return toString(abi.encodePacked(value));
}

function toString(bytes32 value) public pure returns(string memory) {
    return toString(abi.encodePacked(value));
}

function toString(bytes memory data) public pure returns(string memory) {
    bytes memory alphabet = "0123456789abcdef";

    bytes memory str = new bytes(2 + data.length * 2);
    str[0] = "0";
    str[1] = "x";
    for (uint i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        str[2+i*2] = alphabet[uint(uint8(data[i] >> 4))];
        str[3+i*2] = alphabet[uint(uint8(data[i] & 0x0f))];
    }
    return string(str);
}
```

Comment: Beware!! Although the code is well engineered, it leads to this bug: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1432#issuecomment-852044232

Comment: As of solidity 0.8.x, explicit type conversion from address to uint256 is not allowed. So use,   uint256 i = uint256(uint160(address(msg.sender)));

Answer (score 15):

You can cast address to uint160, then use OpenZeppelin Strings library.

```
Strings.toHexString(uint160(address), 20)
```

Reference:

[Casting address to uint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318077/solidity-type-address-not-convertible-to-type-uint256)

[OpenZeppelin Strings for bytes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string/126159#126159)

Comment: Be careful, this will convert a checksummed address into a non-checksummed one

Answer (score 4):

This works with solidity 0.6.0

```
function addressToString(address _pool) public pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
      uint _i = uint256(_pool);
      if (_i == 0) {
          return "0";
      }
      uint j = _i;
      uint len;
      while (j != 0) {
          len++;
          j /= 10;
      }
      bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
      uint k = len - 1;
      while (_i != 0) {
          bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
          _i /= 10;
      }
      return string(bstr);
    }
```

Comment: Works but pay attention: `returns (string memory _uintAsString)` !!! so it is a int, not the address string as you'd expect on first sight. This also means that if your address starts with one ore more zeros (0x**0**A1bC4...), then converting it to an int and then back to hex (address) again will result in this leading **0** missing. You'll need something like this: `'0x' + BigInt(ethAddressAsInt).toString(16).padStart(40, '0')` (40 being the length of an ethereum address, excluding the "0x")

Comment: Could you edit the answer to include this in the function?

Comment: using solidity 8.7, this doesn't compile.  Gives "parser error - expected primary expression" on      bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10)); ]