# Address checksum Solidity implementation

Tags: solidity, addresses, checksum

Looking at [EIP-55](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-55), there are quite a few client-side address checksum implementations provided but no Solidity implementation. Are there any existing examples of computing address checksums directly in Solidity? Not only could an implementing contract be called by clients as a convenience function, but it would also allow for employing on-chain logic based on address checksums. For the latter case, gas efficiency would likely be an important consideration.

Here's an example of an interface that said implementation would inherit:

```
interface AddressChecksum {
  function getChecksum(address account) external pure returns (string accountChecksum);
  function getChecksumCapitalizedDigits(address account) external pure returns (bool[40] digitCapitalized);
  function isChecksumValid(string accountChecksum) external pure returns (bool ok);
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of such an implementation. Usually, interpretation of addresses is only handled client-side. Only handling it client-side also future-proofs your system against future changes in address notation schemes.

Comment: @JesseBusman Thanks, I agree that it makes more sense to handle this client-side in 99.9% of cases. Check out the implementation below if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

I went ahead and put together a working example of EIP-55 in Solidity in case it's useful to anyone that comes across this. It should also be pretty straightforward to create a library that extends `address` with a few of these methods.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;


/**
 * @dev This contract provides a set of pure functions for computing the EIP-55
 * checksum of an account in formats friendly to both off-chain and on-chain
 * callers, as well as for checking if a given string hex representation of an
 * address has a valid checksum. These helper functions could also be repurposed
 * as a library that extends the `address` type.
 */
contract AddressChecksumUtils {
  /**
   * @dev Get a checksummed string hex representation of an account address.
   * @param account address The account to get the checksum for.
   * @return The checksummed account string in ASCII format. Note that leading
   * "0x" is not included.
   */
  function getChecksum(
    address account
  ) external pure returns (string memory accountChecksum) {
    // call internal function for converting an account to a checksummed string.
    return _toChecksumString(account);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Get a fixed-size array of whether or not each character in an account
   * will be capitalized in the checksum.
   * @param account address The account to get the checksum capitalization
   * information for.
   * @return A fixed-size array of booleans that signify if each character or
   * "nibble" of the hex encoding of the address will be capitalized by the
   * checksum.
   */
  function getChecksumCapitalizedCharacters(
    address account
  ) external pure returns (bool[40] memory characterCapitalized) {
    // call internal function for computing characters capitalized in checksum.
    return _toChecksumCapsFlags(account);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Determine whether a string hex representation of an account address
   * matches the ERC-55 checksum of that address.
   * @param accountChecksum string The checksummed account string in ASCII
   * format. Note that a leading "0x" MUST NOT be included.
   * @return A boolean signifying whether or not the checksum is valid.
   */
  function isChecksumValid(
    string calldata accountChecksum
  ) external pure returns (bool ok) {
    // call internal function for validating checksum strings.
    return _isChecksumValid(accountChecksum);
  }

  function _toChecksumString(
    address account
  ) internal pure returns (string memory asciiString) {
    // convert the account argument from address to bytes.
    bytes20 data = bytes20(account);

    // create an in-memory fixed-size bytes array.
    bytes memory asciiBytes = new bytes(40);

    // declare variable types.
    uint8 b;
    uint8 leftNibble;
    uint8 rightNibble;
    bool leftCaps;
    bool rightCaps;
    uint8 asciiOffset;

    // get the capitalized characters in the actual checksum.
    bool[40] memory caps = _toChecksumCapsFlags(account);

    // iterate over bytes, processing left and right nibble in each iteration.
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // locate the byte and extract each nibble.
      b = uint8(uint160(data) / (2**(8*(19 - i))));
      leftNibble = b / 16;
      rightNibble = b - 16 * leftNibble;

      // locate and extract each capitalization status.
      leftCaps = caps[2*i];
      rightCaps = caps[2*i + 1];

      // get the offset from nibble value to ascii character for left nibble.
      asciiOffset = _getAsciiOffset(leftNibble, leftCaps);

      // add the converted character to the byte array.
      asciiBytes[2 * i] = byte(leftNibble + asciiOffset);

      // get the offset from nibble value to ascii character for right nibble.
      asciiOffset = _getAsciiOffset(rightNibble, rightCaps);

      // add the converted character to the byte array.
      asciiBytes[2 * i + 1] = byte(rightNibble + asciiOffset);
    }

    return string(asciiBytes);
  }

  function _toChecksumCapsFlags(address account) internal pure returns (
    bool[40] memory characterCapitalized
  ) {
    // convert the address to bytes.
    bytes20 a = bytes20(account);

    // hash the address (used to calculate checksum).
    bytes32 b = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_toAsciiString(a)));

    // declare variable types.
    uint8 leftNibbleAddress;
    uint8 rightNibbleAddress;
    uint8 leftNibbleHash;
    uint8 rightNibbleHash;

    // iterate over bytes, processing left and right nibble in each iteration.
    for (uint256 i; i < a.length; i++) {
      // locate the byte and extract each nibble for the address and the hash.
      rightNibbleAddress = uint8(a[i]) % 16;
      leftNibbleAddress = (uint8(a[i]) - rightNibbleAddress) / 16;
      rightNibbleHash = uint8(b[i]) % 16;
      leftNibbleHash = (uint8(b[i]) - rightNibbleHash) / 16;

      characterCapitalized[2 * i] = (
        leftNibbleAddress > 9 &&
        leftNibbleHash > 7
      );
      characterCapitalized[2 * i + 1] = (
        rightNibbleAddress > 9 &&
        rightNibbleHash > 7
      );
    }
  }

  function _isChecksumValid(
    string memory provided
  ) internal pure returns (bool ok) {
    // convert the provided string into account type.
    address account = _toAddress(provided);

    // return false in the event the account conversion returned null address.
    if (
      account == address(0)
    ) {
      // ensure that provided address is not also the null address first.
      bytes memory b = bytes(provided);
      for (uint256 i; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (b[i] != hex"30") {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    // get the capitalized characters in the actual checksum.
    string memory actual = _toChecksumString(account);

    // compare provided string to actual checksum string to test for validity.
    return (
      keccak256(
        abi.encodePacked(
          actual
        )
      ) == keccak256(
        abi.encodePacked(
          provided
        )
      )
    );
  }

  function _getAsciiOffset(
    uint8 nibble, bool caps
  ) internal pure returns (uint8 offset) {
    // to convert to ascii characters, add 48 to 0-9, 55 to A-F, & 87 to a-f.
    if (nibble < 10) {
      offset = 48;
    } else if (caps) {
      offset = 55;
    } else {
      offset = 87;
    }
  }

  function _toAddress(
    string memory account
  ) internal pure returns (address accountAddress) {
    // convert the account argument from address to bytes.
    bytes memory accountBytes = bytes(account);

    // create a new fixed-size byte array for the ascii bytes of the address.
    bytes memory accountAddressBytes = new bytes(20);

    // declare variable types.
    uint8 b;
    uint8 nibble;
    uint8 asciiOffset;

    // only proceed if the provided string has a length of 40.
    if (accountBytes.length == 40) {
      for (uint256 i; i < 40; i++) {
        // get the byte in question.
        b = uint8(accountBytes[i]);

        // ensure that the byte is a valid ascii character (0-9, A-F, a-f)
        if (b < 48) return address(0);
        if (57 < b && b < 65) return address(0);
        if (70 < b && b < 97) return address(0);
        if (102 < b) return address(0); //bytes(hex"");

        // find the offset from ascii encoding to the nibble representation.
        if (b < 65) { // 0-9
          asciiOffset = 48;
        } else if (70 < b) { // a-f
          asciiOffset = 87;
        } else { // A-F
          asciiOffset = 55;
        }

        // store left nibble on even iterations, then store byte on odd ones.
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          nibble = b - asciiOffset;
        } else {
          accountAddressBytes[(i - 1) / 2] = (
            byte(16 * nibble + (b - asciiOffset)));
        }
      }

      // pack up the fixed-size byte array and cast it to accountAddress.
      bytes memory packed = abi.encodePacked(accountAddressBytes);
      assembly {
        accountAddress := mload(add(packed, 20))
      }
    }
  }

  // based on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/56499/48410
  function _toAsciiString(
    bytes20 data
  ) internal pure returns (string memory asciiString) {
    // create an in-memory fixed-size bytes array.
    bytes memory asciiBytes = new bytes(40);

    // declare variable types.
    uint8 b;
    uint8 leftNibble;
    uint8 rightNibble;

    // iterate over bytes, processing left and right nibble in each iteration.
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // locate the byte and extract each nibble.
      b = uint8(uint160(data) / (2 ** (8 * (19 - i))));
      leftNibble = b / 16;
      rightNibble = b - 16 * leftNibble;

      // to convert to ascii characters, add 48 to 0-9 and 87 to a-f.
      asciiBytes[2 * i] = byte(leftNibble + (leftNibble < 10 ? 48 : 87));
      asciiBytes[2 * i + 1] = byte(rightNibble + (rightNibble < 10 ? 48 : 87));
    }

    return string(asciiBytes);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/155145/126756) for the first function `getCheckSum()`. It operates on bits and can save some gas (not benchmarked).