# How to hardcode a big list of addresses with bad checksum?

Tags: solidity, addresses, solidity-0.8.x, checksum

I need to hardcode a big list of addresses that don't verify checksum (they're all low caps).

```
address[] private list = [address(this), 0xabc...];
```

Compiler 0.8.17 ends with an error:

```
SyntaxError: This looks like an address but has an invalid checksum. Correct checksummed address: "0x...". If this is not used as an address, please prepend '00'.
```

How can I fix, and translate the big list into checksummed or turn the error into a warning.

The error message suggests the proper checksummed address syntax, but I can't manually fix hundreds of addresses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get an address with a correct checksum, from an address with an incorrect checksum, using Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74765/how-do-i-get-an-address-with-a-correct-checksum-from-an-address-with-an-incorre)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. The `address()` anwser doesn't work. What used to be a warning is now an error.

Comment: ok ill narrow down for you:  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/74772/99976

Comment: Link only answers used to be bad practice in SE.... sorry I don't understand exactly what am I supposed to read in that answer. It's a 3 year old answer that basically says it's impossible. I thought maybe in 3 years people would have found a workaround.

Comment: The compiler will throw an error because the address doesn't pass the checksum; however in your question you said "I can't manually fix hundreds of addresses"; well.. you can, you can use this https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this simple tool that you can use to convert a list of non-checksummed addresses to checksummed addresses.

You can preview it and use it here: https://raw.githack.com/jeremythen/emv-checksum-address-convertor/main/index.html

This is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/jeremythen/emv-checksum-address-convertor

Check the `README.md` file to learn how to use it. But I think it's straightforward. Simply paste the list of non-checksummed addresses and hit the `Convert` button. If your list of addresses has the format `[0xa1..., 0xa2...]`, then check the `Addresses in array?` checkbox so it parses it and returns the result in the same format, ready to copy and paste.

Remember the chain Id. If it's Ethereum, then leave it empty. If it's any other chain, then check the correct chain Id to use here: https://chainlist.org/

You can also use the backend tool in the `index.js` file, to use it with nodejs or something like that.

I hope it helps.

Check the screenshots below for an example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read this

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html#address-literals

'Hexadecimal literals that pass the address checksum test, for example 0xdCad3a6d3569DF655070DEd06cb7A1b2Ccd1D3AF are of address type. Hexadecimal literals that are between 39 and 41 digits long and do not pass the checksum test produce an error. You can prepend (for integer types) or append (for bytesNN types) zeros to remove the error.'

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: you need to evaluate wether or not the address being passed clears the checksum **before** you add it to your array - if it doesn't clear the checksum, prepend '00', then push