# How to convert an Ethereum address to an ASCII string in solidity

Tags: solidity

I've seen another question answered with a solution to this here : [Convert address to string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8346/convert-address-to-string) but it results in an error so I'm re-asking. The error is:
`"TypeError: Operator < not compatible with types bytes1 and int_const 10"`
For context, I'm trying to build a function to dynamically construct a URI which includes the address of the contract where the function lives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution taken from previous posts but fixed in order to avoid casting errors presented on latest Solidity versions...

```
function addressToString(address _address) public pure returns(string memory) {
    bytes32 _bytes = bytes32(uint256(_address));
    bytes memory HEX = "0123456789abcdef";
    bytes memory _string = new bytes(42);
    _string[0] = '0';
    _string[1] = 'x';
    for(uint i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        _string[2+i*2] = HEX[uint8(_bytes[i + 12] >> 4)];
        _string[3+i*2] = HEX[uint8(_bytes[i + 12] & 0x0f)];
    }
    return string(_string);
}
```

Comment: This seems to return the address as a string, but with trailing 'null' characters. For example, if the address 0xaaadeed4c0b861cb36f4ce006a9c90ba2e43fdc2 is passed to the function, the return value (in a js test) is :
'0xaaadeed4c0b861cb36f4ce006a9c90ba2e43fdc2\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000'
I wonder if I can tweak it to trim those off...

Comment: EDIT: I changed `new bytes(51);` to `new bytes(40);` to solve my problem.

Comment: @NickFurfaro Surely you mean `new bytes(42)` (to account for the `0x`)?

Comment: @smarx Yes, thanks./ I did indeed use 42, not 40.