# Address to String in Chainlink Request is giving error?

Tags: tokens, chainlink, oracles, chainlink-vrf, chainlink-automation

When i am using

```
req.add("publicKey","any_public_key_here_as_string");
```

I have 2 steps mentioned in our job specification

```
decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]
fetch        [type=bridge name="adapter" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": {\\"publicKey\\": $(decode_cbor.publicKey)}}"]
```

Result is correct.
[Result Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Cv-MFFZzEgW3e_3UbDB95O30XJQ61NC/view?usp=share_link)

Now, when i am using

```
req.addBytes("publicKey",abi.encodePacked(any_public_key_here));
```

Result is [Result Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEdb5iTcJy4gRlZPiyQXrwOaNtjnMbO3/view?usp=share_link)

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

[Chainlink docs for addBytes](https://docs.chain.link/any-api/api-reference/#addbytes)

the last paragraph for the `addbytes` method says to use `abi.encode(variable)` for types other than bytes, such as an address or array.

If that's not the solution then I can only make a guess with so little code and no inclination of the data type you're trying to call `encodePacked` on or any surrounding syntax but from looking at the json result screenshots, the one that errored out had a value for the public key that was all lowercase like it's failed a checksum test.  either `addBytes` (possibly the chainlink api in general) or `encodePacked` is failing a checksum test or encodePacked is packing the address into a smaller size than chainlink expects.