# Efficiently convert address to truncated uint128?

Tags: solidity

Say I have the following `address`:

`0x9dd1e8169e76a9226b07ab9f85cc20a5e1ed44dd`

I can use this [function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13663/320) to convert it to a `bytes`

```
function toBytes(address a) public constant returns (bytes b){
    assembly{
      let m := mload(0x40)
      mstore(add(m,20),xor(0x140000000000000000000000000000000000000000,a))   //20 bytes in an address
      mstore(0x40,add(m,52))
      b := m
    }
  }
```

It works great!

However, how can I just get the last 128 bits of the address and return a uint128?

e.g. this type of function signature:

```
function toUint128(address a) public constant returns (uint128 u){
    assembly{
      let m := mload(0x40)
      //what goes here??
      //??
      //??
      //mstore(add(m,20),xor(0x140000000000000000000000000000000000000000,a))
      //mstore(0x40,add(m,52))
      u := m
    }
  }
```

And I want the `uint128` equivalent of "0x9dd1e8169e76a9226b07ab9f85cc20a5e1ed", where the last 4 hex chars ("44dd", 32 bits) are removed. This is a 160 bit number minus 32 bits = a 128 bit number.

***Edit:***

This is actually quite simple, all you have to do is:

`uint160 x=uint160(myAddress);`

Comment: Do you mean `uint128 x=uint128(myAddress);` ?  Be aware of which end is being truncated and don't assume that an address is using all 20 bytes.  For instance, some contracts like to burn to specific addresses like `0x0`, `0xdeadbeef` and `0x00000000000000000000000000000000deadbeef` (3 completely different addresses).  In such cases.  If there is for some reason an address that uses limited byte information, it may get birthday collided with another after the casting to int128.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an equivalent of "0x9dd1e8169e76a9226b07ab9f85cc20a5e1ed" - it is 160-16=144 bits ("44dd" == 16 bits). Function **addressToUint144** will do the conversion.

```
contract AddressToUint144
{
    address public constant example_addr=0x9dd1e8169e76a9226b07ab9f85cc20a5e1ed44dd;

    function addressToUint144(address addr) constant
    returns (uint144)
    {
        return uint144(bytes20(addr)>>16);
    }

    //Converting to bytes18 only for good visualization in Remix
    function test()
    returns (bytes18)
    {
        return bytes18(addressToUint144(example_addr));
    }
}
```