# Help to understand assembly method

Tags: solidity, assembly

I have find this assembly code

```
function toBytes(address a) constant returns (bytes b){
   assembly {
        let m := mload(0x40)
        mstore(add(m, 20), xor(0x140000000000000000000000000000000000000000, a))
        mstore(0x40, add(m, 52))
        b := m
   }
}
```

on this post : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13663/17618

There is some things that i don't understand.

Someone can help me to understand this please ?

(I didn't have enough reputation to post a comment on this post, this is why i post a new thread)

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is designed to convert an address to a dynamic bytes type.  Addresses are 20 bytes long, and occupy the right-most 20 bytes of a 32-byte word:

```
0x000000000000000000000000aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The bytes type is two (or more) words: the number of bytes followed by the data. The number of bytes in an address is 20 = 0x14, so it need to look like this in memory.

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014
0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa000000000000000000000000
```

The final thing to know is that Solidity stores the current top of memory in the location 0x40.  So `m` is the top of memory, and is also where we are going to store the bytes version of `a`, namely `b`.

What we want to end up with is:

```
m+0  : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014
m+32 : 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa000000000000000000000000
```

So here are the steps:

1. `let m := mload(0x40)` - sets `m` to current top of memory
2. `xor(0x140000000000000000000000000000000000000000, a)` - puts 0x14 in front of the 20 bytes of address data and returns a 32-byte word padded with leading zeroes: `0x000000000000000000000014aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`
3. `add(m, 20)` - when the result of the `xor` is written, it is shifted 20 bytes relative to the top of memory. This is both clever and dangerous; there's no guarantee that the memory at `m` was empty, and we are not competely over-writing it.  Anyway, this puts the 0x14 where we want it at the end of the word and followed by the `aaaa`s overflowing into the next word.
4. `mstore(0x40, add(m, 52))` - finally we update the top of memory pointer; we've added 52 bytes in total (32 + 20). This would be better as `add(m, 64)` in my view in case anything elsewhere relies on memory being word-aligned, but I may be over-cautious.
5. `b := m` - finally return the (pointer to the) result.

In short, this is very smart, but I would definitely zero-out the two words at top of memory before doing this to avoid any possible issues.

Comment: Hi @benjaminion,
It's very clear !  Thanks you for your help :)