# Is it possible to send a secret message to a specific Ethereum Address using a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, view

I have a secret message that I want to share it with a specific `Ethereum Address` using a smart contract and I want no one else to see it except that specific Ethereum address user. Is it possible?

- If I share it via `event` everyone would see it.
- If I set a variable and code a getter for that, also everyone could access it.

**[Q]** I know that everything is public on the blockchain, but somehow is it possible to keep a string private for the specific user and only that specific user can view it?

Comment: Use Wisper protocol, Its for messaging...

Answer (score -1):

As you stated, everything is public, thus there is not much to "hide". You may add as many heuristics as you want, **anyone persistent enough** will be able to decode it.

Any encoding should be done **before hand** (think: server-side as opposed to client-side).

However, supposing you already know the reader address, one solution is to use [byte-wise XOR operation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/884/how-to-convert-an-address-to-bytes-in-solidity) on the secret message with the reader address.

Think of it as using a **symmetric encryption** with `msg.sender` as a key. 
Your function will be:

```
string your_secret_value

function setSecret(string s) public {
             your_secret_value = s;
} 

function getSecret() public constant returns (string s) {
             return XOR(msg.sender, your_secret_value);

}
```

Then, you compute locally `d = XOR( 0xALLOWED_ADDRESS, your_message )`, and call `setSecret(d)`. This will allow only one specific address to see a message that is not junk.

Comment: Why did you deleted and re-write your answer again. @Betcheg

Comment: Because this method is a valid way of encoding with a non-public key.  I don't think you understand it. In my previous post, every one in the comment was focused on telling me the first method was not safe even though i stated it in the message.

Comment: This is not safe, all Ethereum addresses are public and by knowing those everyone can obtain the secret message via XOR. @Betcheg

Comment: Do you intend to publish the allowed address? If not, how could anyone guess it in the first place ??

Comment: In my case its intended. The addresses are logged on the event. @Betcheg

Comment: Then how do you want to hide something in a fully public environment?? You cannot expect to hide something in a public place in New York City and expect to find it back untouched one month later. Same logic apply here.

Comment: This solution is not safe and secure. Since all Ethereum addresses are public, the secret message is decrypted in `O(N)` time.